# Should we use Mono<T> for non IO Operations?

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is there any benefit/drawback in using Mono vs just ReturnType in a Reactive Java App.

If you are just doing data validation does it make sense to use a Mono

For ex:
Option 1

```
public Mono<String> createEmployee(String name, String dept, String age){
    Employee e;

try {
    e = new Employee(name, dept, age);
  } catch ( ValidationException ve){
    logger.error("Invalid inputs: ", ve);
    return Mono.error(ve);
 }
 return DBUtils.createEmployee(e).flatMap(
    e -> {
     return Mono.just(e.getId());
   }
  );
}
```

Option 2

```
public Mono<String> createEmployee(String name, String dept, String age){
   return Mono.just(new Employee(name, dept, age))
              .flatMap(e -> DBUtils.createEmployee(e))
              .flatMap(e -> Mono.just(e.getId())
              .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Invalid Inputs"));
  }
```

Is there a rule like if there is no IO operation don't use Mono?

Comment: Option 2: Reactor is a concurrency framework, so there is nothing that says you can't use it for whatever you want. You are best served using things in the way they are meant. Option 1 does all the work on a thread while the client is waiting and then creates a concurrent instance to return an ID. Hardly useful. Option 2 creates a concurrent instance to to do the work and returns that to the client. When the client subscribes the work will be done and in the meantime the server can go do other stuff on that thread.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are just doing data validation does it make sense to use a Mono

No, unless that validation could somehow involve a blocking operation (like sending the data to a server to be validated), in which case it would make sense. Here though it just looks like you're processing some logic in a standard method with no blocking operations like API calls at play.

However, in your example you *are* doing something more than validation - it looks like you're actually saving an employee to a database (I assume that's what `DBUtils.createEmployee(e)` does) - and in that case it makes complete sense to use a `Mono`, as that's a textbook use case (allowing you to take a traditionally blocking operation and instead making it part of a reactive chain.)

So assuming the above is true, then option 2 does make sense - but it could certainly be simplified based on two particular guidelines:

- There's no point using `flatMap()` unless your operation actually returns a publisher - otherwise just use `map()` instead;
- There's no point creating a POJO, wrapping it in a `Mono` then mapping it - just start with the publisher as the first element in the chain instead.

So instead of your option 2, it'd be better to use something like:

```
return DBUtils.createEmployee(new Employee(name, dept, age))
          .map(Employee::getId)
          .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Invalid Inputs"));
```

Comment: My intuition says use Mono for network operations. But error handling is a bit tidy using Mono. Helps me avoid the whole try catch blocks.
Is creating a Publisher expensive?

Comment: @Hexy No, not at all expensive.